# how can i get text on tags at selenium by using xpath?

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, webdriver, web-crawler

I'm trying what autotest with selenium, and i want to **scrape** texts from multiple tags by using xpath.

that i want, texts html structure looks like this

```
<div class="roomcard-banner">
    <h2>101</h2>
    <span>text1</span>    
</div>
<div class="roomcard-banner">
    <h2>102</h2>
    <span>text2</span>    
</div>
<div class="roomcard-banner">
    <h2>103</h2>
    <span>text3</span>    
</div>
```

and i want result like this
101, 102, 103

how can i get i want result by using xpath?

could you show me an example? sorry,,,,

my einglish level is very low,,,, please i will wait for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this,

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$n= $xpath->query("/div");
foreach ($n as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeName.' ->'.$node->nodeValue.", ";
}
```

Comment: very thanks for your answer, and can i ask qustion one more?? sorry.,,,,
that is how i can Chaining span tag i want know how i get text in span tag 

i want result --- 
101, text1
102, text2
103, text3

please tell me about this ,,,

Comment: remove h2 from query and check nodeName and nodeValue for $node